# Number of combinations for 9 kids to shout 10 number

Tags: combinatorics

What is the number of combinations for 9 kids to shout 10 numbers from $1,2,...,10$ such that each kid shouts at least 1 number. The order of the numbers is not important (i.e if a kid shouts "1,10" is the same as "10,1"
My initial thought was that we need to choose the first 9 kids, so $9!$, and for the last number we have 9 options so in total: $9!*9$
But the answer is $\binom{10}{2}*9!$. I dont really understand why this is the answer and more important, why is mine wrong?

Comment: This is very unclear, and you never treat the title as the beginning of a sentence continued in the body. The body of the question should be self-contained.

Comment: What was unclear? I edited the body.

Comment: Can you give an example scenario to clarify your question? I'm not sure what it means for nine kids to yell ten number [sic]

Comment: There are infinitely many ways, as the question is stated, since there is no restrictions on the numbers that can be yelled out, nor is there any definition of what "ways" means. If the first kid shouts $10$ then $6$, is that the same as the kid shouting $6$ then $10$?

Comment: The numbers are 1,..,10. If a kid shout 6 and 99 or 99 and 6 it is the same.

Comment: This question can be seen like"How to put 10 objects in 9 boxes such that one box contains 2 objects". So, first select 2 objects out of 10. Make a group of these two. Thus you have 9 groups, one containing 2 objects and other 1object.

Comment: Don't tell us in comments, update the question. It should not be necessary to read comments to understand the question. @YinonEliraz

Comment: Is it that every kid says at least one number or that every number occurs at least once (and each kid says exactly one)?  The latter more closely resembles the solution.

Comment: 8 kids shout 1 number, 1 will shout 2. Total of 10 number and 9 kids.